# What's the direction of parametrization for the following question?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, 3d, parametrization, stokes-theorem

Suppose we want to parametrize the boundary curve of hemisphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=16, y\ge0$, oriented in the direrction of the positive $y-$axis. The answer the book gives is $r(t)=<4\cos(-t),0, 4\sin(-t)>$, and this confuses me because "direrction of the positive $y-$axis" means positive(counter-clockwise) orientation of the circle on $xz$ plane. Why is there negative $t$?

Answer (score 1):

Because in the $xz$ plane,
$
z= r\cos\theta$ and  $x= r\sin \theta
$.

[image]